# Irrlicht - an EventReceiver class in a separate file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, irrlicht

I develop an application, in MSVC++ 10. It is a Irrlicht project. The app draws two simple buttons. In the tutorial I read, it is used a class ***MyEventReceiver***. The class is in the same file as the main. I intend to move the class MyEventReceiver. I have done so, but I received "Access violation error". Did I miss something ? (I mean to initialize something). THe code is as follows:

**main.cpp**

```
      #include <irrlicht.h>
      #include <driverChoice.h>
      #include "CMyEventReceiver.h"
      using namespace irr;
      using namespace core;
      using namespace video;
      using namespace gui;

    int main()
    {
        IrrlichtDevice *device = createDevice(EDT_OPENGL, dimension2d<u32>(640, 480), 16, false, false, false, 0);
        if (!device)
            return 1;
        device->setWindowCaption(L"Irrlicht Test");
        IVideoDriver *driver = device->getVideoDriver();
        IGUIEnvironment *guienv = device->getGUIEnvironment();
        IGUIFont *font = guienv->getFont("../debug/lucida.xml");
        guienv->addButton(rect<s32>(250, 20, 250 + 120, 50), 0, GUI_ID_QUIT_BUTTON, L"Exit", L"Exits Program");
        guienv->addButton(rect<s32>(400, 20, 400 + 120, 50), 0, GUI_ID_NEW_WINDOW_BUTTON, L"New Window", L"Launches a new Window");
        SAppContext context;
        context.device = device;
        CMyEventReceiver receiver(context);
        device->setEventReceiver(&receiver);
        while(device->run())
        {
            driver->beginScene(true, true, SColor(255, 128, 192, 255));
            guienv->drawAll();
            driver->endScene();
        }
        device->drop();
        return 0;
    }
```

**CMyEventReceiver.h**

```
    #pragma comment(lib, "Irrlicht.lib")

    #include <irrlicht.h>
    #include <driverChoice.h>

    using namespace irr;
    using namespace gui;
    using namespace core;

    struct SAppContext
    {
        IrrlichtDevice *device;
    };

    enum
    {
        GUI_ID_QUIT_BUTTON = 101,
        GUI_ID_NEW_WINDOW_BUTTON
    };

    class CMyEventReceiver : public IEventReceiver
    {
    public:
        CMyEventReceiver(SAppContext &context);
        virtual bool OnEvent(const SEvent &e);
    private:
        SAppContext *sac;
    };
```

**CMyEventReceiver.cpp**

```
    #include "CMyEventReceiver.h"

    CMyEventReceiver::CMyEventReceiver(SAppContext &context) {}

    bool CMyEventReceiver::OnEvent(const SEvent &e)
    {

        if (e.EventType == EET_GUI_EVENT)
        {
            s32 id = e.GUIEvent.Caller->getID(); 
            IGUIEnvironment* guienv = sac->device->getGUIEnvironment();
            if (e.GUIEvent.EventType == EGET_BUTTON_CLICKED)
            {
                if (id == GUI_ID_QUIT_BUTTON)
                {
                    sac->device->closeDevice();
                    return true;
                }
                if (id == GUI_ID_NEW_WINDOW_BUTTON)
                {
                    IGUIWindow* window = guienv->addWindow(rect<s32>(100, 100, 300, 200),false, L"New window");
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

If I let the code in the file (with some minor corrections) it works. I preffer to have it as a separate file, it is more elegant and more useful.

Thank you for your patience.

Ee Bb

Comment: Could you please provide some more detail on the error. On what part is it saying "Access violation error"?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you failed to assign the `sac` member variable in your `CMyEventReciever` constructor.

```
CMyEventReceiver receiver(context);
```

However, your constructor is this:

```
CMyEventReceiver::CMyEventReceiver(SAppContext &context) {}
```

Basically a "do-nothing" constructor.

The fix should be this:

```
CMyEventReceiver::CMyEventReceiver(SAppContext &context) : sac(&context) {}
```

However, `sac` relies on a pointer to be "alive" when the object actually uses it.  So IMO seems like a flawed design, but for the simple main() program, should be OK.

Now if the program were more complex, then you should investigate using a `std::shared_ptr<SAppContext>`, so that pointer will only die when the program dies.

Comment: @Arpit In CMyEventReceiver.cpp just before            IGUIEnvironment* guienv = sac->device->getGUIEnvironment();

Comment: I changed in the CMyEventReceiver.cpp in the following way:   CMyEventReceiver::CMyEventReceiver(SAppContext &context) {} : sac(&context){}   Unfortunately I received an error. I guess tockange the declaration also in CMyEventReceiver.h, but I don't know how.